# email with pdf attachment and cc addresses

Tags: c#, email

I used the [this website](http://www.silverlightnext.com/2010/06/send-email-from-silverlight-application.html) to set up my email service and it seems to be working great but I can't figure out how to add a pdf with the email and cc two email addresses.

Portion of C# code:

```
EmailServiceClient emailClient = new EmailServiceClient();
emailClient.SendEmailCompleted += 
    new EventHandler<SendEmailCompletedEventArgs>(emailClient_SendEmailCompleted);
//MessageBox.Show(SelectedFeatureLayer.ID);

if (SelectedFeatureLayer.ID == "AllAvailableFeatureLayer" || 
    SelectedFeatureLayer.ID == "AMAvailableLayer") {
    if (msgToAM.Length != 0 & msgToAM != "Type email here" & 
        Regex.IsMatch(msgToAM, @"^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$")) {
        //MessageBox.Show("create new message");

        SLEmailMessage AMemailMessage = new SLEmailMessage {
            To = msgToAM,
            From = "name@email.org",
            Subject = "Thanks to Bike Count Volunteers",
            Body = AMmsgBody
        };

        emailClient.SendEmailAsync(AMemailMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: I do think the single `&` should be `&&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to add the following, plus republish my app and update my service reference:

SLEmailMessage.cs:

```
    [DataContract]
public class SLEmailMessage
{
    [DataMember]
    public string To { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string From { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string CC { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Bcc { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Attachment { get; set; }

}
```

EmailService.svc.cs:

```
 [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[SilverlightFaultBehavior]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class EmailService
{
    [OperationContract]
    public bool SendEmail(SLEmailMessage emailMessage)
    {
        bool IsEmailSendSuccessful = false;

        try
        {
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(emailMessage.From, emailMessage.To);
            mailMessage.CC.Add(emailMessage.CC);
            mailMessage.Bcc.Add(emailMessage.Bcc);
            var pdfMessage = new Attachment(emailMessage.Attachment);
            pdfMessage.ContentDisposition.FileName="BikeCountInfo.pdf";
            mailMessage.Attachments.Add(pdfMessage);
            mailMessage.Subject = emailMessage.Subject;
            mailMessage.Body = emailMessage.Body;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Send(mailMessage);
            IsEmailSendSuccessful = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            IsEmailSendSuccessful = false;

        }

        return IsEmailSendSuccessful;
    }


    // Add more operations here and mark them with [OperationContract]
}
```

update service and republish app - then add:

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
            if (SelectedFeatureLayer.ID == "AllAvailableFeatureLayer" || SelectedFeatureLayer.ID == "PMAvailableLayer")
        {
            if (msgToPM.Length != 0 & Regex.IsMatch(msgToPM, @"^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$"))
            {
                SLEmailMessage PMemailMessage = new SLEmailMessage
                {
                    To = msgToPM,
                    From = "email@name.org",
                    CC = "email@name.org",
                    Bcc = "email@name.org",
                    Attachment = "location of attachment",
                    Subject = "Thanks to Bike Count Volunteers",
                    Body = PMmsgBody
                };
                emailClient.SendEmailAsync(PMemailMessage);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/425435/WCF-email-web-service-error-exception-when-sending